# Qmake does not include the library path for qt

Tags: linux, qt, qmake

I just install qt on my slax box, 
And I tried to write and compile using qmake.

But the problem is qmake does not write it's 'Makefile' to include -Lqt-mt or -Lqt.
I have to give it manually otherwise there are unresolved links are there. What I could 
do for this?Any workaround on this?

[image]

And this is the 'Makefile' output by the qmake.

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: hello
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.5.3) on: Tue Feb 2 04:04:03 2010
# Project:  hello_world.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /usr/bin/qmake -unix -o Makefile hello_world.pro
#############################################################################

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = 
CFLAGS        = -pipe $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/lib/qt-3.3.8b/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I.
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = 
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)   
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
QMAKE         = /usr/bin/qmake
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = $(COPY) -r
INSTALL_FILE  = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -sf
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = ./

####### Files

SOURCES       = hello_world.cpp 
OBJECTS       = hello_world.o
DIST          = hello_world.pro
QMAKE_TARGET  = hello
DESTDIR       = 
TARGET        = hello

first: all
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.C.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

####### Build rules

all: Makefile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS)  
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)

Makefile: hello_world.pro  /usr/lib/qt-3.3.8b/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf 
    $(QMAKE) -unix -o Makefile hello_world.pro
qmake:  FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -unix -o Makefile hello_world.pro

dist: 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) .tmp/hello1.0.0 || $(MKDIR) .tmp/hello1.0.0 
    $(COPY_FILE) --parents $(SOURCES) $(DIST) .tmp/hello1.0.0/ && (cd `dirname .tmp/hello1.0.0` && $(TAR) hello1.0.0.tar hello1.0.0 && $(COMPRESS) hello1.0.0.tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname .tmp/hello1.0.0`/hello1.0.0.tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r .tmp/hello1.0.0


clean:compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DEL_FILE) *~ core *.core


####### Sub-libraries

distclean: clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(TARGET) 
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile


compiler_clean: 

####### Compile

hello_world.o: hello_world.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o hello_world.o hello_world.cpp

####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

And here is my .pro file that I used.

```
TEMPLATE=app
CONFIG+= qt warn_on release
HEADERS=
SOURCES=hello_world.cpp
TARGET=hello
```

I already set the $QTDIR and I think everything is in place. 
Where I missed? Why I have to give it manually? Why qmake does not work in first
place?

EDIT:
There in makefile

```
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)
```

What I did is change it to,

```
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -lqt-mt
```

After I changed everything works fine ! The problem is again , why I have to do such 
a thing manually?

FOR @Frank Osterfeld
I think I'm using correct 'qmake' because ,
When I hit, qmake --version , I do get this.

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.5.3 in /usr/lib/qt/lib
```

--Thanks in advance--

Comment: what is the result of the command `qmake -query` ?

Comment: it's a makefile I'll post it.

Comment: What does your project file look like?

Comment: Post the .pro file. Which Qt version do you want to use, Qt3 or Qt4? You seem to run a qt3 qmake on a Qt4 .pro file.

Comment: No I'm not mixing Qt3 and Qt4, this is Qt4 application. 
That's why I set $QTDIR to qt4 configuration mkspace. I'll post the .pro file anyway.

Comment: @sandundhammika There's definitely a mix-up between Qt3 and Qt4 somewhere.  Your Makefile has numerous a couple of references to Qt3 make specifications.  Also, Qt4 does not have a "qt-mt" or "qt" library.  Using CONFIG += qt should get you the QtCore and QtGui libraries.

Comment: @RA. I do agree with you, I think you're above comment more sounds constructive. Even I set the $QTDIR something is messing with Qt3. I want to dig it. May be I have to read the qmake source code for this.

Comment: @sandundhammika Some other things to try: 1. Ensure that your Qt4 bin directory is before your Qt3 bin directory in your $PATH.  2. Ensure that $QMAKESPEC points to a Qt4 make specification.  3. Ensure that $QT_PLUGIN_PATH is also set to your Qt4 directory.  4. If all else fails, check Qt in your entire environment with something like env | grep -i "qt"

Comment: @RA. setting the $QMAKESPEC to $(QTDIR)/mkspecs/linux-g++ solves it.
Please put your above comment as an answer. So I could give some credits for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are multiple Qt installations on a machine, it's important the environment has been set-up properly to point to the right Qt version.  The following are important environment variables to check:

1. `$QTDIR` -- should point to the base directory for the Qt installation.
2. `$QMAKESPEC` -- should point to a make specification directory under `$QTDIR` (e.g. `$QTDIR/mkspecs/linux-g++`).
3. `$QT_PLUGIN_PATH` -- should point to the plug-in directory, typically within the Qt installation (e.g. `$QTDIR/plugins`).
4. `$PATH` -- should have the `$QTDIR/bin` directory within it.  The installation that you wish to use should be first within the `$PATH`.

If all else fails, check your full environment to ensure that the correct Qt installation is being referred to (use `env` on *nix, `set` on Windows).

If you notice directories pointing to the wrong installation within the `Makefile` generated by `qmake`, it is likely that your environment hasn't been properly set (in this case, `$QMAKESPEC` was the culprit).

Finally, it's important to note that the libraries from Qt3 are no longer present in Qt4: Qt3 has `libqt-mt`, `libqui`, etc.  Qt4 has `libQtCore`, `libQtGui`, etc.

Comment: Or better do not f..k yourself with this variables and use proper `qmake` executables. May be `qtchooser` will help. The only thing you will provide to `qmake` is `-spec` parameter, which could be found in `qtbase/mkspecs`. Good luck.